# Error inflating class NavigationView from XML

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, navigationview

I'm using `NavigationView` in my MainActivity. Now, My App runs fine in `Android 5.0` and above. but, It doesn't run in `Android 4.0.4`. It shows me `XML` error in `<NavigationView />`.

I've than added `multidex` support by thinking it should help. but, it didn't.

Currently I've 4 icon in `NavigationView` & 1 launcher icon in `header_layout`. so, I don't think it should `OutOfMemoryError`.

Here's My Code

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gripxtech.kasimrangwala.unipayretailer"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.malinskiy:superrecyclerview:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.codinguser.android:contactpicker:3.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile project(':materialdatetimepicker-library')
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_main" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I can't figure out what to do. Thanks in advanced.

**UPDATE**

Here's my Logcat Error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gripxtech.kasimrangwala.unipayretailer/com.gripxtech.kasimrangwala.unipayretailer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
at com.gripxtech.kasimrangwala.unipayretailer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
at com.gripxtech.kasimrangwala.unipayretailer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:190)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:250)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:172)
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:94)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
at com.gripxtech.kasimrangwala.unipayretailer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) 
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:190) 
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:250) 
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:172) 
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:94) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
at com.gripxtech.kasimrangwala.unipayretailer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/side_nav_bar.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020059
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1899)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:286)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:120)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) 
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:190) 
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:250) 
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:172) 
at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:94) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
at com.gripxtech.kasimrangwala.unipayretailer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2 at android.content.res.Typ
```

**Update 2**
Here's my `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.drawer_layout)
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Bind(R.id.nav_view)
    NavigationView mNavigationView;

    TextView mUserFullName;
    TextView mUserBalacne;

    private static final String PREFERENCES_FILE = "mymaterialapp_settings";
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition;

    SessionManager mManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setUpNavDrawer();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void setUpNavDrawer() {
        Menu menu = mNavigationView.getMenu();
        menu.getItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition).setChecked(true);
        loadFragment(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
        setUpNavView();
        setUpUserData();
    }

    public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout() {
        return mDrawerLayout;
    }

    public NavigationView getNavigationView() {
        return mNavigationView;
    }

    public TextView getmUserFullName() {
        return mUserFullName;
    }

    public TextView getmUserBalacne() {
        return mUserBalacne;
    }

    public void setUpNavView() {
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                menuItem.setChecked(true);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_recharge:
                    if (mCurrentSelectedPosition != 0) {
                        loadFragment(0);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.action_refill_wallet:
                    if (mCurrentSelectedPosition != 1) {
                        loadFragment(1);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.action_payment:
                    if (mCurrentSelectedPosition != 2) {
                        loadFragment(2);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.action_logout:
                    logout();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void setUpUserData() {
        View view = mNavigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        mUserFullName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNavUserFullName);
        mUserBalacne = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNavUserBalance);

        mManager = new SessionManager(MainActivity.this);
        mUserFullName.setText(mManager.getUserFullName());
        mUserBalacne.setText(mManager.getUserBalance());
    }

    public void logout() {
        mManager.setLogin(false);
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }

    public void saveSharedSetting(int settingValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, settingValue);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public int readSharedSetting() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPref.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, 0);
    }

    public void loadFragment(int currentSelectedPosition) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = currentSelectedPosition;
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (mCurrentSelectedPosition == 0) {
            setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            fragment = RechargeTabsFragment.newInstance();
        } else if (mCurrentSelectedPosition == 1) {
            setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.action_refill_wallet));
            fragment = WalletFragment.newInstance();
        } else if (mCurrentSelectedPosition == 2) {
            setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.action_payment));
            fragment = PaymentFragment.newInstance();
        }
        clearBackStack();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_content_main, fragment).commit();
        saveSharedSetting(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    public void clearBackStack() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        for (int i = 0; i < fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mr.icetea Sorry, for late reply. I've added my logcat error. Please, visit it. Thanks

Comment: @mr.icetea Above error occurs only when I run my app on device prior to `Android 5.0`. Otherwise It runs like charm.

Comment: @mr.icetea Please, See my answer. Thanks to you for suggesting me to  concentrate on LogCat error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I've found it.

1st of all Here's my `nav_header.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNavUserFullName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="@string/nav_title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNavUserBalance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nav_sub_head" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, Concentrate on Line no. 5.
`android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"`
It's nothing but gradient.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="135"
        android:endColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:startColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

I've change the color value like this.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="135"
        android:endColor="@color/primary_dark"
        android:startColor="@color/primary"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Now, It's running on Android 2.3.3 Emulator.
Hope this will help some in future.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct dependency to the Android Design Support Library. It's easy to choose the wrong one - because it seems that Google postet two different dependency strings:

At the time of this answer, the [Android developer blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) (and the comment by user hungryghost) had the correct dependency string, while the dependency string on the [Support library](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/tools/support-library/features.html#design) homepage does not work.

Use this one: compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

Note that the version is 22.2.0 (wrong: 22.0.0) and that the package is called design (wrong: support-design)

After these changes use the Android Studio menu "Rebuild project", or the "Sync" button that appears sometimes after changing the gradle file.

Comment: Refer my answer. I always consider to use 'Everything updated' but, Your answer is also acceptable. Thanks for useful info.