# Signed APK : Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am stuck with this error. This is happening only in signed `apk`. Not sure why its happening. I tried few solutions given in other posts [Error inflating class NavigationView from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467010/error-inflating-class-navigationview-from-xml). 
When I am running in debug it works perfectly fine . But when I try signed `apk` I get this error.
Build config is:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
        }
    }
```

I tried removing progaurd but still doesn't work
Please help me.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.xyz.abc, PID: 3358
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xyz.abc/com.xyz.abc.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
      at android.support.v7.app.aj.f(Unknown Source:23)
      at android.support.v7.app.a.setContentView(Unknown Source:4)
      at com.xyz.abc.ui.b.onCreate(Unknown Source:8)
      at com.xyz.abc.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:0)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
      at android.support.design.internal.c.b(Unknown Source:12)
      at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source:154)
    10-08 02:59:15.675 3358-3358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(Unknown Source:1)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
      at android.support.v7.app.aj.f(Unknown Source:23)
      at android.support.v7.app.a.setContentView(Unknown Source:4)
      at com.xyz.abc.ui.b.onCreate(Unknown Source:8)
      at com.xyz.abc.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:0)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
   Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class android.support.v7.widget.ac: void android.support.v7.widget.ac.h(android.support.v7.widget.cp) failed to verify: void android.support.v7.widget.ac.h(android.support.v7.widget.cp): [0x92] invoke-super/virtual can't be used on private method void android.support.v7.widget.ac.d(android.support.v7.widget.cp)
   void android.support.v7.widget.ac.s() failed to verify: void android.support.v7.widget.ac.s(): [0xB6] invoke-super/virtual can't be used on private method void android.support.v7.widget.ac.d(android.support.v7.widget.cp) (declaration of 'android.support.v7.widget.ac' appears in /data/app/com.xyz.abc-52DjgJ17eJPimoZOoEeG8A==/base.apk)
      at android.support.v7.widget.cr.<init>(Unknown Source:79)
      at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
      at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView.<init>(Unknown Source:1
```

Comment: You have minified enabled set to true. Are you sure you are not losing the class due to progruard?

Comment: @Juan If that's the case should I change the progaurd config or disable minifyenabled? I am new to android please suggest.

Comment: Turn it to false and see if that is the problem. If it is then you can decide wha to do. You may need to do some googling to see how to preserve the missing classes. Or you may choose no to use proguard by leaving mification turned off.

Comment: I resolved by skipping the package in progaurd file.